# socket.io send an object to a html table

Tags: socket.io

I am a real newbie  - I was given a leg up to create something and it is using socket.io. I'm trying to fiddle around the edges, learning odd things as I go now. But have hit a wall in a really early stage of my project. It May well be too deep ... but just in the case asking here gives me an answer I can make sense of - here goes:

I have essentially three files working together. server.js, client.js, and index.ejs (which is my html file). I have a series of stuff happening in a "room" and now I want to display the values (next I will want to do more with them, but for now display) of an object in a html table.

server.js
... it creates the information of interest (uses a database call that currently works) and then:

```
         io.to(roomId).emit('room-location-update', result.rows);
```

client.js
... receives data. My console.log has it all there. Then I assign a variable to hold it for use in the html:

```
socket.on("room-location-update", (data_information) => {
  console.log(data_information);
  //I think I need code in here?
  var wp = data_information;
}
```

index.ejs
... fails to show anything. I have a table constructed to use the variable from client.js in a series of table cells essentially all constructed as:

```
<td id=wp.name><td id=wp.radius>
```

but nothing is displayed. the .name and .radius attributes are valid in the database when data_information is first created.

why nothing displayed? Google searches imply (to me) that this is basic stuff and should work. So clearly I am missing something basic (?) Any ideas what?

Comment: What is the rendering engine you are using? This is a node app?

Comment: it is a node (npm?) app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, I don't actually know what you are talking about with edits. Apologies if I have done something wrong - I am a genuine newbie.

In the end I gave up on doing it in the ejs file and created a big string containing the html table codes and substituting in values where I wanted them in the client.js. And just popped that into the ejs file. No idea if this is efficient or not but it works, so hooray.

truncated code snippet of what worked for me (in client.js):

```
  var $table = "<table border='1'>"
  $table += "<thead><tr><th>Player</th><th>Location</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
  for (var i = 0; i < display_information.length; i++) {
     $table += '<tr><td>' + display_information[i].id + '</td>'
     $table += '<td>' + display_information[i].name + '</td>'
  }
  $table += "</tr></tbody></table>"
  $('#displayinfo').empty().append($table);
```

and then in my index.ejs is:      `<pre><span id="displayinfo"></span></pre>`